# Generate new prefab using prefab after edit in runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have simple script and work perfect, but only runing in Unity Editor. I Try build for mobile, not complete and error build. i using Unity 2019.3.4.
Is there a subtitute "using UnityEditor" for mobile script.

I need script for mobile. Any idea for running in mobile.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Prefabz : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject selObj;

        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                CreatePrefab();
            }
        }

        void CreatePrefab()
        {
            //GameObject[] selObjs = Selection.gameObjects;

                string charName = selObj.name;

                // duplicate
                GameObject newInstance = Instantiate(selObj);
                newInstance.name = charName;

                // now replace the prefab
                string prefabPath = "Assets/trideeScript/" + charName + ".prefab";
                var existingPrefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(prefabPath, typeof(GameObject));
                if (existingPrefab != null)
                {
                    PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(newInstance, existingPrefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ReplaceNameBased);
                }
                else
                {
                    PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab(prefabPath, newInstance);
                }

                // delete dupe
                DestroyImmediate(newInstance);

                Debug.Log("Prefab'd " + charName + "! \"" + prefabPath + "\"");
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UnityEditor namespace is not supported on any platform, except actually Editor. That's why all editor scripts must be placed inside "Editor" folder, and that's why it's a good practice to keep any editor-related stuff inside pre-processor directives `#if UNITY_EDITOR`

Comment: hmmmm... how to run it for mobile?
thanks in advance..

Comment: Prefabs are the same resources, as your images, sounds or scriptable object instances. There are compiled inside your game, and game can not modify itself after compilation. So you can not do this.

Comment: Instead, you can convert your object (GameObject, for example) into string, using, for example, unity's JSONUtility. Then you can store this string into PlayerPrefs, or write into HDD as file. Then, at game start, you should read this string, de-serialize it (convert back to object). And then, you can use this object as a prefab for Instantiate().

Comment: There are a lot of options, depending of what do you need to achieve. You can use binary serialization, instead of text - it will restrict user from manually modifying file. Or you can upload it on your server. Also there are asset bundles, which are useful to deliver new content to already compiled apps (but not for export content from app).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try convert to a string and save into PlayerPrefs or Database ... thank you very much @Mykhailo